# How to create view, group by or filter on publish status?

Tags: document-library, versioning, publishing

I created a document library. The library has the following version settings below. I have some documents which are published and have a major version. Other documents are draft and has a minor version. How can I group or filter on published status? I would like to filter on draft documents? Or filter on published documents.

[image]

**UPDATED**

I created a calculated field like Domenico suggested me. It looks like when I add the calculated field it works. When I modify some document in the library it doenst work anymore. I see #Name? as value, but I expecting "Published" or "Draft". See printscreen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,
you should create a calculated field based on version.
And then group your documents by the new calculated field.

Here the full explanation:

- Create a calculated field based on Version; Formula syntax    is like
  Excel formula (see link;
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx
  )
- You should split the version string by the "."(dot) character and then check if major an minor version define a document as Draft or
  Publish (apply your criteria here)
- Draft | Publish, are two of possible values of your calculated field
- Create views that filter or group documents by that value

Comment: Do you have more information about the calculated field? Do you know the formule?

Comment: I have updated my answer. There is a link to a page that explains calculated field's formula.

Comment: If you explain me which is the criteria to define a document as Draft or Published. I might help you more.

Comment: Ciao @Ola, has my answer resolved your issue?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Please give me an example of the formule to filter on all documents with major versions.

Comment: Ciao Ola, here the formula that you are looking for.
=IF(INT(LEFT(Version,FIND(".",Version)-1))>0,"Published","Draft")
Please, remember to set my post as Answer for your question.

Comment: Ofcourse I will mark your post as the answer. But your example is not working. Please see my update.

Comment: I had the same issue. Change the sting Published in the formula with a differente string (Publ. for example) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your pages view showing an "Approval Status" column?

You can filter on that column, or you could create views that show pages according to the status.

Comment: I dont have column "Approval Status" because this option is disabled. We dont want to enable this option.

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old post in case it helps someone. Like Marc said we can use the "Approval Status" column (internal name - "_ModerationStatus") to solve the problem. We can either add this column to an existing view or create a new view using PnP PowerShell.

```
 Add-PnPView -List "Site Pages" -Title "Pages with Approval Status" -Fields "Name","Modified", "_ModerationStatus"
```

[image]